# Randomly permute matrix rows keeping same-valued rows adjacent

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation

How can I randomly permute row keeping those with the same value adjacent to each other?  I know that I can use `randperm` on the rows to randomly permute all rows, but I do not know how to keep the same-valued rows adjacent.  Thanks.

```
A = [0 0 0;
     0 0 0;
     1 1 1;
     1 1 1;
     1 1 1;
     2 2 2;
     2 2 2];   

 permute_A = [0 0 0;
     0 0 0;
     2 2 2;
     2 2 2;
     1 1 1;
     1 1 1;
     1 1 1];
```

Comment: so you want to permute the blocks? are the columns always identical? is it possible to have two separated blocks of the same value? ie `[x 1 1 x x 1 1 1 x x]`?

Comment: @GuntherStruyf I think permuting the blocks is what I want to do.  Generally, the columns will always be the same, and for the first effort we can assume that they are.  The blocks will not be separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to identify the clusters and then permute them:

Finding the clusters can be done by finding the changes in their differences:

```
diffA = diff(A);
clusters_start = [1 ; find(any(diffA,2)~=0)+1];
```

Then the cluster ends are easily found by:

```
clusters_end = [clusters_start(2:end)-1 ;size(A,1)];
clusters_length = clusters_end-clusters_start+1;
```

now you know the number of clusters and you can permute them:

```
Nclusters = numel(clusters_start);
perm_idx = randperm(Nclusters );
clusters_start = clusters_start(perm_idx);
clusters_end = clusters_end(perm_idx);
clusters_length = clusters_length(perm_idx);
```

and put them in a new matrix:

```
newA = NaN(size(A));
for ii=1:Nclusters
    newA(sum(clusters_length(1:ii-1))+(1:clusters_length(ii)),:) = A(clusters_start(ii):clusters_end(ii),:);
end
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking about something similar. I think you could do it a bit simpler though.